# What does "ufunc did not contain a loop with signature matching types" mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I have code that I thought was great. I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ablev\eclipse-workspace\matrix\matrix.py", line 149, in <module>
    print("Transpose of matrice is:\n" + transpose(subtract())),
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U25'), dtype('int32')) -> None
```

What does this mean?

```
def matrix_one():
    print("Enter your first 3x3 matrix: ")
    global matrix1
    matrix1=[]
    for i in range(3):
            while True:
                row=input().split()
                row=list(map(int,row))
                if len(row) != 3:
                    print(f"Please enter 3 rows of 3 columns of\
numbers separated by a space: ")
                else:
                    break
            matrix1.append(row)
    
    print("Your first 3x3 matrix is: ")
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(matrix1[i][j],end=" ")
        print()

def matrix_two():
    print("Enter your second 3x3 matrix: ")
    global matrix2
    matrix2=[]
    for i in range(3):
            while True:
                row=input().split()
                row=list(map(int,row))
                if len(row) != 3:
                    print(f"Please enter 3 rows of 3 columns of\
numbers separated by a space: ")
                else:
                    break
            matrix2.append(row)
    print("Your second 3x3 matrix is: ")
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            print(matrix2[i][j],end=" ")
        print()

def subtract():
    '''function to subtract results of matrix'''
    results = np.subtract(matrix1,matrix2)
    return results
def transpose(function):
    '''transpose function'''
    transpose = np.transpose(function)
    return transpose()
matrix_one()
matrix_two()
subtract()
print(subtract())
print("Transpose of matrice is:\n" + transpose(subtract())),
```

Comment: The last line of the `transpose` function is suspect: `return transpose()`. I'm not sure you want those parentheses. Though I guess I'm not sure of the argument name in the function either, The input should be an array, I think, not a function. Your use of global variables makes all of this code harder to read and understand than it should be.

Comment: The error says you can't add a string ('U') and a number.  Use `print('transpose', value)`,  In other words, use a comma, not a plus in the print expression.

Comment: Gold, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments pointed out,

```
print("Transpose of matrice is:\n", transpose(subtract()))
```

instead of

```
print("Transpose of matrice is:\n" + transpose(subtract()))
```

will solve your problem since the operator + need strings as arguments, and the result of transpose is not a string but an np.array.

Another approach would be to make `transpose()` return the string representation of the matrix, like so:

```
def transpose(function):
'''transpose function'''
trans = np.transpose(function)
return str(trans)
```

Leaving out the extra parenthesis.